# SELECT ascending ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select rows for insertion and need an ascending ID - how to?

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, ColA, ColB)
SELECT (SELECT max(ID) + 1 FROM myTable), colA, colB FROM myOtherTable
```

Unfortunately, this results in:

```
5, 'a1', 'b1'
5, 'a2', 'b2'
5, 'a3', 'b3'
```

I need to have

```
5, ...
6, ...
7, ...
```

Is there some constant I can use instead of `+1` to have an ascending ID? Something like `+@ROWNUM`...

Comment: whether you are just trying to sequence row or you are trying to sequence row on maximum of ID value ? why can't you use `identity` for ID column ?

Comment: Because the ID column is no identity (yeah, don't ask me...), I want to have ascending IDs starting with 1 after the existing maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, much simple

```
SELECT (select MAX(ID) from table1)+row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col1, col2) ID,
       col1, 
       col2
  FROM table1
```

Comment: Even simpler than my own solution, nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS IDSEQ
```

Comment: Close, see my answer.

Comment: Still upvoted your answer, as it pointed me into the right direction. Don't know who downvoted you though.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the maximum value we can increment the value

```
Declare @i int;

    DECLARE @TABLEA  TABLE (PK INT,custno VARCHAR(10),cno VARCHAR(10))

    DECLARE @TABLEB  TABLE (PK INT,custno VARCHAR(10),cno VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO @TABLEB (PK,custno,cno) VALUES (5,'a1','b1'),(5,'a2','b2'),(5,'a3','b3')
    Select @i = max(pk)  from @TABLEB;

    INSERT INTO @TABLEA (PK, custno,cno)
    Select @i + ROW_NUMBER() over(order by custno)   , CustNo,cno
    FROM @TABLEB

    SELECT * FROM @TABLEA

    SELECT * FROM @TABLEB
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to adapt jimmy8ball's answer (removed the `PARTITION BY` part to make it work):

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, ColA, ColB)
SELECT (SELECT max(ID) FROM myTable) + x.rownum, x.colA, x.colB 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) FROM myOtherTable) x
```